# How output name player online minecraft-server-util

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

The console displays the **id**, **name** of the players, I need to display only the **name** list.

**How can I do this?**

**Code:**

```
const util = require('minecraft-server-util');
util.status('xxx.xxx.xx.xxx', { port: xxxxx, enableSRV: true})

  .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.onlinePlayers);
      console.log(response.samplePlayers);
  })
```

**response.onlinePlayers** outputs to the console: 3 online server

**response.samplePlayers** outputs to the console:

```
[
  { id: '54bc4231-79as-3290-bce6-6585c28aa931', name: 'Alexs21' },
  { id: '63c3f66e-c4ff-438a-ba23-4102a70140e6', name: 'Steve12' },
  { id: '30в625d5-305e-205d-a72e-76281654ffd8', name: 'Anton666' }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to append that info to the body of the HTML page, use:

```
for (i in response.samplePlayers) {
    $("body").append(response.samplePlayers[i].name);
}
```

Comment: What about "favicon"?

Comment: you can use $("body").append("<img src='icon.png'>" + response.samplePlayers[i].name);

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < response.samplePlayers.length; i++){
  console.log("name :" + response.samplePlayers[i].name);
}
```

`response.sampleplayers` is an array. You simply want to read the value of the property `name` of each element of this array.

Answer (score 0):

### Most efficient way of filtering out would be to use `map()`:

```
  const nameArr = response.samplePlayers.map(obj => obj.name);
  //returning only the name property of every object element of response.samplePlayers.

  console.log(nameArr); //outputs array - ['Alexs21','Steve12','Anton666']
```

### In case of old browsers, you can simply use -

```
const nameArr = []; //declare an empty array

for(var i = 0;i < response.samplePlayers.length;i++) {
    nameArr.push(response.samplePlayers[i].name); //populate name property to nameArr
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (response.onlinePlayers != 0) {

   for (var i = 0; i < response.onlinePlayers; i++) {

      console.log("name :" + response.samplePlayers[i].name);

   }

} else {

   console.log("No One Is Online");

}
```

this is what I use and it works

Comment: consider adding more explanation instead of just saying "i use this and haha it magically works"